# Editing multiple lines in TextBox

Tags: vb.net, multiline, multilinestring

I want my program to take a string entered into a TextBox and then convert it in a pattern. Here is my current code:

```
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    For Each line As String In TextBox1.Lines
        TextBox1.Text.Insert(0, """")
        TextBox1.Text.Insert((TextBox1.Text.Length), """")
        TextBox2.AppendText(line & vbCrLf)
    Next
End Sub
```

I don't want these changes to be done to the entire TextBox, but to each individual line. So

```
1111
1111
```

would turn into

```
"1111"
"1111"
```

instead of

```
"1111
1111"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't going to be able to for-each it, so you would have to loop through your Lines collections.  Easier to do this backwards, since inserting text will change index positions and so on, so try it this way:

```
For i As Integer = TextBox1.Lines.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
  If TextBox1.Lines(i).Length > 0 Then
    Dim startPos As Integer = TextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(i)
    TextBox1.Select(startPos, TextBox1.Lines(i).Length)
    TextBox1.SelectedText = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", """", TextBox1.Lines(i), """")
  End If
Next
```

Comment: This works very well, but would you mind explaining how this works? Thanks!

Comment: You can get the first character index of each line through that GetFirstCharIndexFromLine function.  All I do is highlight the text starting from that position with a length of the text from that line, then I replace the entire contents with the new text.

Comment: Makes so much more sense! Thank you for taking the time to help me out!

Comment: Nice answer! Though I have a thought: [**According to the documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines(v=vs.110).aspx) the `Lines` property is both `Read/Write`, so shouldn't it technically be possible to just do: `TextBox1.Lines(i) = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", """", TextBox1.Lines(i), """")`?

Comment: @VisualVincent The Lines "collection" is replaceable with a string array, but the TextBox ignores any individual elements in the Lines array if you try to tinker with it.  So I could have copied the lines array to my own variable, muck with it, then replace the whole thing, too.